# Restoring backed up Linux Partition

Tags: system-installation, grub, backup

Suppose we have an empty drive `/dev/sda` with lots of space. We also have a partition of a previous Linux backup `/dev/sdb1`. This contains the usual linux filesystem `/home`, `/usr`, etc. What is notably missing is the EFI boot partition.

From this setup, how would we

1. Copy the partition over to `/dev/sda`, leaving space for a boot partition
2. Create a boot partition that boots into this file system
3. Install grub to boot into this from BIOS

Answer (score 1):

First off,  mount `/dev/sdb1` on `/src`.  I know you don't have a /boot/efi in your image, but I don't know whether your /boot was separate. Check whether there's an entry for `/boot` in `/src/etc/fstab`. If there is, we'll have to recreate that as well.

> Copy the partition over to /dev/sda, leaving space for a boot partition

Instead, create the EFI boot partition first (GPT table, make the first partition a 4 GB FAT32 partition, label "EFIboot" for identification).

Make sure you've formatted the partition (`sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1`, assuming sda1 is the partition name), then note down the UUID you get with `sudo lsblk -o UUID /dev/sda1` (we'll call it `uuid_efi`).

If there was an entry for `/boot` in `/src/etc/fstab`, also make a 4GB partition (ext4, nothing special) for that.  Note down the UUID of that as well (we'll call it `uuid_boot`).

Add an appropriately sized partition on sda for the contents of `/dev/sdb1`, format it (hint: using the same file system type as the original enables the default configuration of your system to still use it) and mount it on `/dst` and `cp --archive /src/* /dst/`. This might take a while!

Adjust `/dst/etc/fstab` so that `/boot/efi` is a mount of `UUID=${uuid_efi}`. If there was a `/boot` entry itself, adjust it to be `UUID=${uuid_boot}`, both as noted above.

Bind-mount `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev` and `/run` into `/dst`:

```bash
for mnt in {proc,sys,run}; do
  sudo mount -o bind "/${mnt}" "/dst/${mnt}"
done
```

And finally open a shell that sees the `/dst` directory as `/`:

```bash
sudo chroot /dst /bin/bash
```

If present, mount `/boot`; then mount `/boot/efi` from within that shell

```bash
mount /boot
mount /boot/efi
```

Tada. Now you have a shell that sees everything as if it was running on the booted target system.

The usual distro-specific methods for reinstalling the boot-loader apply here. For debianoids, that's [this way](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall), for redhatoids, it's probably `yum reinstall grub2-efi`. For other distros, you need to do your own research (Search engine for `distroname reinstall grub` should work). Then use the distro-specific way of reinstalling the recent kernel package, to populate /boot/ properly and regenerate the initrds.